# Fully defined objects - smart dimension (like solidworks)

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am coming from solidworks, and what I am looking for is something similar to the "smart dimension" tool. In blender I can control the dimensions by extruding, grabbing, and scaling by defined amounts, but if I want to change that dimension later, other dimensions are not locked. Basically, I have to have already designed the model in its entirety on paper before I begin. Changes to early dimensions force starting from scratch or scrapping the "fully defined" nature of the model.

I learned these techniques from Robert Burke's 2007 on using precesion modeling with blender. book:http://homepage.ntlworld.com/r.burke2/precision_modelling1.html

I am hoping that there might be a new tool or plugin that allows for a fully defined workflow?

Comment: Maybe you could illustrate your question with some images? What do you mean with "dimensions"? The edge lenght info in edit mode?